# When buying Windows 8 in German, is it possible to install it in English?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot-camp, language

I have a Mac and want to install Windows 8 via BootCamp on it as well.
I signed up on microsoft.at and now I'm facing two questions.

**First off.** The product says "Windows 8 Upgrade". What does that mean? That I already need to have a license for a previous version? 
http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/mseea/de_AT/pdp/productID.275219500

I simply want to buy a Windows 8 license (a serial key) and want to download the installation file, so I can run it with BootCamp.

**My second question** is about the language. Since I'm from Austria I can only purchase via the austrian Microsoft site. The product says "Productlanguage" is german. I wonder if I purchase this Windows 8 package if I'm able to install Windows in english.

I need an english version of Windows 8.

Comment: A `Windows 8 Upgrade` license requires a previous version of Windows XP, Windows 7, or Windows Vista installed on the system. Only `Windows 8 System Builder` allows you to install Winows 8 on a hdd that does NOT contained a previous installation of Windows. `Windows 8 Upgrade` does allow you to do a `Clean Installation` if you choose to do that. You can use any Windows 8 image you have access and simply use your license key.  **This comment isn't answer quality, if I did post it as an answer, despite it being correct it would be likely downovted by the community.

Comment: I think it's unbelievblay difficult to purchase Windows 8 :) Never seen such a complex process before. I simply want to buy Windows 8 and a valid license. I could of course also pirate it which would probably be easier :)

Comment: I think only some people choose to make it unbelievblay difficult to purchase Windows 8. There are only two licenses types `Upgrade` license and `System Builder` license. If you don't have a previous version of Windows purchase the `System Builder` license. I won't bother on the rest of your comment considering its not productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 Upgrade: you need to have a previous Windows OS license.

In your case you need a Windows 8 OEM license. You can not buy this online. You should turn to resellers. (Find resellers: http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/)

In Windows 8 you can change language after installing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607

Comment: Microsoft does NOT sell OEM/System builder licenses online. Third party resellers however may sell OEM licenses online. This: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msus/en_US/pdp/productID.264951000 is an upgrade license!